# Crash when deleting row and tableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

When trying to delete row in tableview with :

```
 [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:swipedIndexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Where indexPath is valid and gives the right cell, i am getting this crash log :

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2903.23/UITableView.m:1330
```

Cant figure out why ?

Comment: Have you updated your data source to remove the object? You should wrap the delete and updating of the datasource in the tableView methods `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if your

```
(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

is returning a value 1 less than that of before calling '`deleteRows`..'

This might be your problem. If you are deleting a row from the tableview UI, your backend data should delete it too.